# Is FaceTime available on iPad?

Tags: ipad, facetime

I'm trying to decide if I want to buy an ipad.  My question is, Will I be able to connect with family members who have iPhones on FaceTime if I have an iPad ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the iPad also comes with the Facetime app, except not if you buy it in Saudi Arabia or the UAE, and if you buy it in China the audio will not work.

I think Skype works everywhere, and I have sometimes found it more reliable than facetime, but others have the opposite experience.

Comment: as long as you have sufficient bandwidth (EG WiFi, preferably) or solid LTE connectivity. If you go down to 3G or have spotty coverage Facetime may cut out or even refuse to work.

Comment: Are you saying Skype is most of the time less reliable and more subject to freezes? What does that have to do with FaceTime with iPhone users?

Comment: IMO. FaceTime works a lot better than Skype. I've noticed FaceTime working even under 2G connectivity while Skype couldn't even connect.